# Connect two points in $\mathbb R^3$ using integral lines of some vector fields

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Suppose we are in $\mathbb R^3$ and let $\nu\in S^2$ be fixed. We have a regular function $u:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R$ with the following property:

- $u$ is decreasing along the integral lines of the constant vector field $\nu$, i.e. $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\leq 0$;
- $u$ is constant along the integral lines of any  constant vector field $\nu'$ orthogonal to $\nu$, that is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu'}= 0$.

We want to show that there exists a  regular function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that $f'\leq 0$ and $u(P)=f(P\cdot \nu)$.

I think this is done if one can show that:$$\forall P,P'\in \mathbb R^n: P\cdot \nu=P'\cdot \nu \implies u(P)=u(P') \quad (*).$$
I've seen that $(*)$ is true in the easier case where $\nu=(0,0,1)$, for example, because we can connect two points $P=(x,y,z), P'=(x',y',z)$ following the integral lines of the vector fields $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$, where $u$ is constant by hypothesis. 
I think we can do something similar with $\nu$ general too, so my idea would be to connect $P,P'$ using integral lines of vector fields orthogonal to $\nu$, but I get stuck because I can't formalize the argument.

Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you (as you claimed) know how this is done for $\nu=(1,0,0)$ you are done, since, by an orthogonal transformation, you can always choose your coordinate system in such a way that $\nu$ takes this form, and the problem is, quite obviously, invariant under this kind of transformation.

Comment: Ok, so do you think that if one shows $(*)$ then we have the existence of $f$ with those properties?

Comment: @Claretta While I did not adress this in my answer, this is true as well. If, e.g.,  $\nu = (1,0,0)$ you can take (define) $f(x) = u(x, 0, 0)$ or $=u(x, y_0, z_0)$ for any fixed $(y_0, z_0)$ -- this is assuming that, in fact, $u$ is defined and, say, $C^1$ on all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the properties you have listed.